# Retrieve window dimensions in OCaml Graphics

Tags: windows, graphics, size, ocaml

I would like to know if it is possible to retrieve the window dimensions from Graphics module ?

Since I am using a tiling window manage, the window is never in the dimensions choosen dimensions...
I don't know other modules like Gtk and I have two days yo finish my project so it might be a little quick to learn new modules...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Graphics](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Graphics.html), there is size_x & size_y:

```
val size_x : unit -> int
```

See Graphics.size_y.

```
val size_y : unit -> int
```

Return the size of the graphics window. Coordinates of the screen pixels range over 0 .. size_x()-1 and 0 .. size_y()-1. Drawings outside of this rectangle are clipped, without causing an error. The origin (0,0) is at the lower left corner.

Isn't it what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API in Graphics.